# Can Heroku's dyno cycling be adjusted?

Tags: heroku

I would like to increase the rate at which my background workers cycle. Maybe have them automatically restart every 12 hours instead of every 24. Is this a config option on Heroku?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to do this, but the only reasonable option to achieve this is to have each of your background dynos kill itself after 'N' hours, or 'N' messages processed. Amount of hacking needed for this depends on your environment.

Comment: We're having a weird issue where segfaults are silently killing our background workers. Obviously, we're trying to solve the root problem, but increasing the cycling will help ensure that our servers are actually working.

Comment: Writing some code to manually trigger the restarts isn't hard, but heroku has already built it all. I just wanted to check if there was a config variable which would take care of it for me.